# AngularJS empty nested array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have one main controller, which performs AJAX request to fill the $scope.leader object. In the child controller, I'm trying to access this data.
After loading my $scope.leader looks like so:

```
{
  teams:[
    {
      name: "team 1",
       members: [
           {
              name: "member"
           }
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Could you please, anybody explain the following behaviour:
When I do console.log($scope.leader), I get the proper data set. But then I do console.log($scope.leader.teams) I'm getting empty array.

Comment: I would suggest you debug your JS-File and use the "watch" - area of chrome for example to add "$scope.leader". instead of using the console There you can watch the object in complete

Comment: you should do console.log in ajax success fucntion

Comment: inside success object has proper form. The prooblem is, that, in the nested (child) controller nested array is empty once I try to log it out.